# Selected option cannot display in option tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have the options that I want to filter using javascript based on a selected item into another
option tag, but it not working, 
if the selected element contains 'CONTINUE' or 'BRACKET' in it, then split it based on a space into an array and take only the 1st and 2nd index and concatenate it this way, then add it an array with some extra string.

And in the for loop am splitting the array based on the '|' and put them in html  tag based on the if condition above. But portion is not displaying the result in the  tag, any help please.
please take a look of my code that I have uploaded.

Thank you.

```js
function products(s5,s6){

var vr = /CONTINUE/;
var vr1 = /BRACKET/;
var proname = document.getElementById(s5);

var protype = document.getElementById(s6);

protype.innerHTML = "";

if(vr.test(proname)){
// if the selected element contains 'CONTINUE' in it, then split it based on a space 
// into an array and take only the 1st and 2nd index and concatinate it this way, then 
// add it an array with some extra string.

  var nw = proname.split(" ");
  var nw1 = nw[0]+' '+nw[1];
  var nw2 = nw1+" FULL PROFILE"+' | '+"FULL PROFILE";
  var optionAray = [" | Select product type"];
  optionAray.push(nw2);
  //alert([optionAray]);
} else if(vr1.test(proname)){
    // if the selected element contains 'BRACKET' in it, then split it based on a space 
    // into an array and take only the 1st and 2nd index and concatinate it this way, then 
    // add it an array with some extra string.

    var nw = proname.split(" ");
    var nw1 = nw[0]+' '+nw[1];
    var nw2 = nw1+" BRACKET PROFILE"+' | '+"BRACKET PROFILE";
    var optionAray = [" | Select product type"];
    optionAray.push(nw2);
  //alert([optionAray]);
} 
for(var option in optionAray){
    // here am splitting the array based on the '|' and put them in html <option> tag based on the
    // if condition above.
    // But portion is not displaying the result in the <option> tag, any help please.
  var pair = optionAray[option].split("|");
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = pair[0];
  newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
  protype.options.add(newOption);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<center><label>Select to filter</label><br><br>
    <td>ProductName</td>
          <td>
            <select name="product_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" onchange="products(this.id,'prtype')">
              <option value="">Select product name</option>
              <option value="SMART LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SMART LINE</option>
              <option value="SEA LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SEA LINE</option>
              <option value="SQUARE LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SQUARE LINE</option>
              <option value="SLIM LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SLIM LINE</option>
              <option value="SMALL LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SMALL LINE</option>
              <option value="STAR LINE BRACKET PROFILE">STAR LINE</option>
              <option value="SKY LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SKY LINE</option>
              <option value="SPARK LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SPARK LINE</option>
              <option value="SLEEK LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SLEEK LINE</option>
              <option value="SUPER LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SUPER LINE</option>
              <option value="SIGNATURE LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SIGNATURE LINE</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="prtype" id="prtype">
              
            </select>
          </td></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var proname = document.getElementById(s5)
```

to

```
var proname = document.getElementById(s5).value
```

This will give you the value of the element, instead of the element itself.

Comment: Wow its works!! that was so quick and simple thing I didn't notice and this have taking me all night. I really appreciate it Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)